# How to render an image on the screen C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been trying to create a test program that just displays a bitmap image on the screen for a while now. Ideally, the image would be translucent (have an alpha channel) and "click throughable." However, I have not found any way to do this.

The application that I have for this is a keyboard indicators app that runs in the background and displays a popup image onscreen for a couple seconds whenever a modifier like num lock or caps lock is pressed.

What I have found is an MSDN example [for how to render an image on the screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-render-images-with-gdi#to-render-an-image-with-gdi), but I haven't been able to make this work properly in a Windows Forms app. In the `Form1.cs` of a blank WFA app, I have:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KeyboardIndicators
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
            pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("Profile Image.jpg");
            Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
            g.DrawImage(myBitmap, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

I am probably missing a lot here, but I am not having much luck debugging it in Visual Studio.

I have yet to find a site online that fully describes how to do something like what I would like to do. I have seen this kind of thing done before in other apps, so I know it can be done somehow.

Comment: To make the "click throughable" part, override `CreateParams()`, set the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Override ... in what scope? Form1?

Comment: That's correct, in whatever form you want to be invisible to clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question thanks to the initial answer by @Habeeb on this question, which inspired me to research that method. By looking at [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13103870/3339274), I realized I didn't need to create a helper function to do this. To @Idle_Mind's point also, I [set the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/173800/3339274).

This is the code I ended up with in my `Form1.cs` file: (I ended up changing the test image to `cube.png`, a `.png` image with an alpha channel)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KeyboardIndicators {
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();

      PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();

      Image myBitmap = Image.FromFile("cube.png");
      Size bitmapSize = new Size(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);

      this.Size = bitmapSize;
      pictureBox.ClientSize = bitmapSize;

      pictureBox.Image = myBitmap;
      pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      this.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
      this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
      get {
        CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
        createParams.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT

        return createParams;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When run, the following is shown onscreen:

[image: Screenshot of running program]

This works for me, as it is overlayed on all apps I need, is semi-transparent and is click-throughable.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I do not see the Bitmap image is set to the PictureBox.
Please try the below code:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage ;
MyImage = new Bitmap(fileToDisplay);
pictureBox1.ClientSize = new Size(xSize, ySize);
pictureBox1.Image = (Image) MyImage ;
```

If you want to add PictureBox via code, see below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var picture = new PictureBox
    {
        Name = "pictureBox1",
        Size = new Size(xSize, ySize),
        Location = new Point(100, 100),
        Image = Image.FromFile("hello.jpg"),

    };
    this.Controls.Add(picture);
}
```

The first piece of code shows how to update image, but a different approach.

Comment: If I just use the code you suggested, (replacing the path and size with the proper values) nothing is displayed. The file path is just the file name (as a string) if the image is imported into the project? My Solution Explorer looks [like this](https://imgur.com/s9l7lDt). The test image is `Profile Image.jpg`.

Comment: Did you add the pictureBox1 control to the form?

Comment: What control should I add?

Comment: PictureBox. I should be added to the form. For instance, you had created a new PictureBox control in code, but not added to Form.

Comment: Sure, but how can I do that?

Comment: See the updated answer to show how PictureBox is added to Form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165770/discussion-between-ifconfig-and-habeeb).